# When do we have $\log(\prod^{\infty}_{i=0}a_i)=\sum^{\infty}_{i=0}\log(a_i)$?

Tags: complex-analysis

This shows up in convergence of the Euler product and I don't know in what condition this holds. Here $a_i$ is a complex sequence. Is this an equivalent condition?

Comment: Should one of those be a sum?

Comment: certainly holds true if $a_i = 1, \forall i$ but it should be a sum not a product in both terms.

Comment: The left hand side equals $\sum_{=0}^\infty \log a_i$

Comment: Yes.. one of those is a sum.

Comment: Generally, for complex numbers $\log (xy)= \log x +\log y$ does not hold.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is straightforwardly true if the $a_i$ are all positive reals; just argue by induction that

$$\log (\prod_{i=0}^n a_i) = \sum_{i=0}^n \log a_i$$

and then take the limit as $n \to \infty$ (and use the continuity of $\log$).

If the $a_i$ are complex then both the LHS and the RHS are ambiguous and one must specify a branch of the logarithm. In that context it's true if one takes the [principal branch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_branch) of the logarithm and the sum of the arguments of the $a_i$ remains bounded in absolute value by $\pi$. In general if you're not careful about branches then the LHS and the RHS may differ by an integer multiple of $2 \pi i$, so you just need to set things up to make sure this doesn't happen.

Comment: When can one side converge and the other not? I suppose (given we work with the principal branch)  the only possible problem is when the RHS converges and *your* LHS $\lim\log\prod$ diverges because the partial products keep jumping across the branch line, but that does not affect OP's $\log\lim\prod$

Comment: @Hagen: aha, thanks.